# Laravel - Dynamically Loading Models And Return View on fail

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to dynamically load models based on what is being passed to it.

```
    class MyController extends Controller{
        $modelClass = "";
        public function __construct(){
            $this->setModel($modelName);
            }
        public function index(){
          $this->data['rows'] = $this->modelClass::all();
          return view('index', $this->data);
        }
        protected function setModel($modelName){
         if(!class_exists('\App\Models\\'.ucfirst($modelName)) || empty($modelName))
        {
            return view('page500');
        }else{
            $this->modelClass = '\App\Models\\'.ucfirst($modelName);
        }
        }
       }
```

I kept getting the error message "FatalThrowableError
Class '' not found". I expect laravel to stop execution once a view have been returned but the execution isn't loading the page500 view and isn't stopping the execution.

Comment: Result of `return view('page500');` is returned to `__construct`. And that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setModel` function returns a view to it's callee function, `__construct`. And that's all it does.

To immediately raise certain error - use `abort` function with error code as argument:

```
if(!class_exists('\App\Models\\'.ucfirst($modelName)) || empty($modelName))
{
     abort(500);
}
```

To modify error page layout - follow [this instruction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#custom-http-error-pages). Or simply create file `resources/views/errors/500.blade.php`.

Comment: Works perfectly well. Thank you so much.